# Temos permissão para remover respostas das perguntas?

Tags: debate

Hoje presenciei um caso, onde um contribuidor novato, adicionou no campo de respostas o complemento de sua pergunta,

Como devemos proceder quanto a isso?

É sábio considerar e usar a paciência com o propósito de instruí-lo ou pode ser removido?

Comment: O procedimento é sinalizar para a moderação. Caso seja relevante, o conteúdo pode ser movido para a pergunta. Tudo depende do caso concreto. Sobre a remoção, depende dos pontos. Usuários comuns podem votar para remover conteúdo que não consideram relevante ou respostas que não são respostas, via votação, se tiverem os pontos suficientes para isso. Ainda, como tudo que é removido tem histórico (e o autor da postagem continua tendo acesso), nada impede dele mesmo mover a informação para o campo correto.

Comment: Então posso sugerir que ele faça a exclusão do conteúdo da resposta e respectivamente adicionar na pergunta o conteúdo, deixando assim a pergunta no formato coerente com a política referente as perguntas no formato correto, certo?

Comment: É uma possibilidade. A outra é sinalizar a postagem (usando a opção de outros assuntos) e a moderação avaliar e fazer a mudança usando ferramentas do sistema se for adequado.

Comment: Compreendi, irei sinalizar futuramente quando encontrar outras, a citada em questão já houve uma resolução.

Comment: Irei remover esta pergunta para não gerar poluição no META.

Comment: @HyagoSantos. Não remova a pergunta, tanto a pergunta e os comentários são importantes no futuro para orientar a comunidade caso surja dúvidas similares. Mantendo a pergunta o debate estará aberto a outros posicionamentos e pontos de vista apreendidos com o próprio desenvolvimento da comunidade.

Comment: Material complementar, [Sinalizar Publicações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).

Comment: @AugustoVasques, okay, permanecerá aberto.